# How can I put back my ping command in english?

Tags: linux, ping, kde

I recently add a the japanese language to my system and, from here, my PING command is in japanese :

```
➜ ping 1.1.1.1
 PING 1.1.1.1 (1.1.1.1) 56(84) バイトのデータ
64 バイト応答 送信元 1.1.1.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 時間=16.0ミリ秒
--- 1.1.1.1 ping 統計 ---
送信パケット数 2, 受信パケット数 2, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 14.908/15.472/16.037/0.564 ms
```

Here is my locale :

```
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I tried to set LC_ALL with`export LC_ALL="fr_FR.UTF-8"` but it didn't changed the ping output language

I don't think I saw another command in japanese.

I'm on Archlinux with KDE Plasma

Can you help me for put it in english or french again please.

Thank you for your help !

Comment: try to set LC_ALL if still not working check *which ping* is compromised

Comment: Set LC_ALL doesn't work, ping is on `/usr/bin/ping`

Comment: i have no clue what i am talking about but just for the sake of completeness check *realpath /usr/bin/ping* and *file /usr/bin/ping*

Comment: `/usr/bin/ping` is the real path. Weird thing, if I do `/usr/bin/ping -h` (or simply `ping -h`), the result is in english...

Comment: also the words packet loss time are in english, maybe what you see is hostname for that ip

Comment: btw i don't like that language packs. i am always using linux in english lang because it's terrible to google for a german terminal output from apt / dpkg / compiler error messages. sometimes translation is more confusing than helpful. keep it simple, use en

Comment: It's not hostname, it's translation of what it should be in english.

Comment: I think for now I'll just remove the language from kde (not really usefull to keep it...), thank you for your help

Comment: hopefully there will be more qualified response

Comment: In a comment you said "set LC_ALL doesn't work". This information should be in the question body. Please [edit] the question. With my privileges I can edit for you, but the actual command you used would be better than "set LC_ALL doesn't work". So please edit and post the actual command(s) that didn't work.

Comment: Ok, I did that.